# Notify email when someone's posted a review in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I noticed that Woocommerce's reviews are managed through Wordpress Comments. But why is it that Wordpress isn't notifying my email when someone posted a review to a product. I have set the "Email me whenever anyone posted a comment".

Is this function available in Woocommerce or i'm missing something?

Please advise, thanks everyone!

Regards, Ven

Comment: mine works fine... maybe something is wrong with your setup (host, email, etc..)

Comment: try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/thank-me-later/

Comment: @Reigel hmmmm not really i've tested by posting a new dummy order and it emails the target email recipient which is a gmail account and it works.

i've also checked Woocommerce > Settings > Emails and pointed to that gmail account and all the transactions are emailing quite fine.

Also in Settings > General > Email Address same gmail account.

but the reviews are not sending notification to that gmail account.

Comment: @vrajesh i'm not emailing the one who posted the review in the product but thanks for that too :)

Answer (score 6):

By default Wordpress sends a notification to the author of the product/post (the person who created the product in your instance). The suggested site owner (settings > general) is not the recipient of these notifications. This is where the trouble might start. This author information is in Woocommerce hidden and is hard to figure out who that is in your user database. It might be that the original author of the product doesn't exist anymore, and especially if the original author has been deleted from the database and you didn't move the contents of that user to a new user.

The default comment notifications are produced in this Wordpress file: `wp-includes/pluggable.php`

Below is a trick to override the recipient for the comment/review notification, put this code in your child-theme's `functions.php` and change the part `example@example.com` to your desired email recipient and you will receive a notification every time someone adds a comment/review to your site.

```
function new_comment_moderation_recipients( $emails, $comment_id ) { 
    return array( 'example@example.com' );
}
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'new_comment_moderation_recipients', 24, 2 );
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'new_comment_moderation_recipients', 24, 2 );
```

I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

On the Wordpress Dashboard navigate to Settings > General and the Email address listed here is where you will get notifications.